# Bayes' Law Practice Problem

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, bayes-theorem

Two percent of men who participate in Covid 19 screening have the disease.
Ninety-two percent of those with the disease test positive. Six percent of the men who do
not have Covid 19 will also have positive test results. Given that a man has a positive test result, what is the probability he also has the disease?

My approach is this:

$P(T+|D) = 0.92$

$P(T+|D') = 0.06$

$P(D) = 0.02 -> P(D') = 0.98$

$P(D|T+) =$ $\Large\frac{P(T+|D) P(D)}{P(T+|D) P(D) + P(T+|D') P(D')}$

= $\Large\frac{0.92* 0.02}{0.92 * 0.02 + 0.06 * 0.98}$

Does this seem correct?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: @Aisha: Yes, ok.